# How do I print the full pipeline of which my script is one part of?

Tags: bash

Using `echo "blah" | myscript`, as an example pipeline am looking for a way to from within "myscript":

```
echo "$SOME_BUILTIN"
```

whose output would be the original pipeline:

```
echo "blah" | myscript
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

siblings=($(pgrep -P "$(ps -p $$ o ppid=)" | grep -Fvx $$))
pids=$$
sibling=$$

while true
do
    pid=$sibling
    for sibling in ${siblings[@]}
    do
        if [ "$(readlink "/proc/${sibling}/fd/1")" = "$(readlink "/proc/${pid}/fd/0")" ]
        then
            # Found previous pipe process
            pids="${sibling},${pids}"
            continue 2
        fi
    done
    break # No previous pipe process
done

while IFS= read -r line
do
    pipeline="${pipeline+${pipeline} | }$line"
done < <(ps --sort=pid -p "$pids" o args=)
printf '%s\n' "$pipeline"
```

Example:

```
$ ./test.sh
bash ./test.sh

$ cat /dev/zero | sleep 1 | ./test.sh
cat /dev/zero | sleep 1 | bash ./test.sh
```

Working on a small [project](https://github.com/l0b0/pspipe) to make this a proper tool.

Comment: This prints the components of the original pipeline, not the original pipeline itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to do this directly, but you could use following information to recreate the pipeline:

- Your script's PID is in `$$` env variable
- Using `ps -fe` and looking at columns 2 and 3 you can find your script's parent and the parent's parent and so on. The pipeline consists of a series of direct ancestors, and you can follow the path down to process with PID 1 (`init` process or equivalent).
- Knowing each process's PID, you can get its command line from `/proc/PID/cmdline` (replace `'\0'`'s with spaces using `tr` for human-readable format
- If you know that the script was called from a pipeline, you're essentially done. If you need to find out whether it was called from a pipeline or interactively, you would probably need to check what `ls -lh /proc/self/fd/0` prints. That's the 0-th file descriptor, meaning stdin. If it points to `/dev/someting` (like `/dev/pts/XX`) you're probably interactive. If the target of the link starts with `pipe:[`, it's likely you are receiving data from a pipeline (it could also be a network socket but hopefully you can rule this case out as unlikely in your setup).